# Adding Loop in the File Command Python

Tags: python, file, loops

ı wanna create a file which as :

X values:

```
1
2
3
4
5
.
.
.
999
```

to do that ı wrote that command but ;

error like :`argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not float`,,

```
from numpy import *

c = open("text.txt","w")
count = 0
while (count < 100):
   print  count
   count = count + 0.1
   c.write (count)
   c.close
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want `count = count + 1`, in any case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When writing to a file, you must write *strings* but you are trying to write a floating point value. Use `str()` to turn those into strings for writing:

```
c.write(str(count))
```

Note that your `c.close` line does nothing, really. It refers to the `.close()` method on the file object but does not actually *invoke* it. Neither would you want to close the file during the loop. Instead, use the file as a context manager to close it automatically when you are d one. You also need to include newlines, explicitly, writing to a file does not include those like a `print` statement would:

```
with open("text.txt","w") as c:
    count = 0
    while count < 100:
        print count
        count += 0.1
        c.write(str(count) + '\n')
```

Note that you are incrementing the counter by 0.1, *not* 1, so you are creating 10 times more entries than your question seems to suggest you want. If you really wanted to only write integers between 1 and 999, you may as well use a `xrange()` loop:

```
with open("text.txt","w") as c:
    for count in xrange(1, 1000):
        print count
        c.write(str(count) + '\n')
```

Comment: But he want to increase one by one

Comment: @Ugur: That is a **separate** issue.

Comment: Only answer that fixes everything. +1

Comment: thank u.. now thats clear for me . ı wanna have one addıtıonal question how can ı over write random float Values, over  that file with commands,, for example
X
1
2
3  and ı wanna over wrıte like ;

    X Y
    1 2.5
    2 3.6

Comment: Write a *new* file, then replace the old file with that new one.

Answer (score 0):

also, you're closing your file on each iteration of the while loop, so this will write your first line and then crash.

Unindent your last line so that the file's only closed after everything's been written to it:

```
while (count < 100):
    print  count
    count = count + 0.1
    c.write(str(count))
c.close()
```

Comment: No, the `c.close` does *nothing*. It is a no-op. It references the method without calling it.

Comment: right, i focused on the indentation and completely overlooked this. I'll edit and fix my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems which I can see are :
1. You can only write character buffer to file. The solution to main question u asked.

```
c.write (count) should be c.write (str(count))
```

2. You need to close your file outside the loop. You need to unindent c.close

```
from numpy import *    
c = open("text.txt","w")
count = 0
while (count < 100):
   print  count
   count = count + 0.1
   c.write (count)
c.close()
```

3. Even after these this code will print and save numbers incremented with 0.1 i.e 0.1,0.2,0.3....98.8,99.9 You can use xrange to solve your problem.

```
result='\n'.join([str(k) for k in xrange(1,1000)])
print result
c = open("text.txt","w")
c.write(result)
c.close()
```